# ReSharper reductio ad absurdum?

Tags: c#, resharper

Here's an interesting one:

Resharper wants to morph this:

```
var lc = new LoginCredentials();
lc.Username = "CesarChavez";
lc.Password = "CesarChavez";
```

...into this:

```
var lc = new LoginCredentials {Username = "CesarChavez", Password = "CesarChavez"};
```

...but with the latter, "lc" seems superfluous - it's not referenced anywhere...???

Comment: You mean you don't want to use `lc` for something later on? What's the point of it then?

Comment: Resharper is suggesting a way of reducing the number of lines of code. It should then grey out lc, indicating that it is superfluous and can be removed as it is not used, if it is not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not used in your first code block either.  It assumes (and rightfully so) that you'll use `lc` at some point, otherwise the entire block is pointless.

Comment: ReSharper also doesn't know what the `LoginCredentials` constructor is going to do.  So it will next offer to eliminate `var lc =`, leaving just a call to the constructor and ignoring the resulting object.  As [Guy L. Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele) said, "_... the ability to define your own operator functions means that a simple statement such as x=a+b; in an inner loop might involve the sending of e-mail to Afghanistan._"